# Subfolder named 'php' in a Openshift PHP application returns 503

Tags: php, openshift

I've spent 3 days trying to debug why I was getting a 503 error.

When I created the PHP 5.4 application with HAproxy, the URL would return the generic page.
Then I copied pasted my code from my github repo into it and the site returned 503 not available responses. Strange. Inside the log, I would get:

> [Thu Mar 27 06:41:28 2014] [error] [client 127.2.200.1] client denied
>   by server configuration:...

So I began removing files and adding back them one by one. Turns out, when I removed a subfolder called 'php', the error went away. Then I brought it back under a new name and the errors went away. Same code just different directory structure.

I think this is a bug but I didn't see any document that says I can't have directories named php. Any thoughts on what I'm seeing?

*Edit: Forgot to mention, I don't have the git repo available on github right now but it can be made available if you want to help me out with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

php is one of the optional document root names per this blog post (https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog), so if you include a folder named php, but it does not contain an index.php file, then your site would return a 503 error.